# Solving for a single element of a solution of a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, iterative-method

I wish to solve a linear system $A x =b$ in which $A$ is dense but not too large, say no larger than $10\times10$. However, I am not interested in the full solution vector $x = [x_0, x_1, \dots]$, rather I only care about accurately determining $x_0$. I know that Cramer's rule can compute $x_0$ directly, but this requires the evaluation of two determinants. It is my understanding that calculating these determinants is not typically faster than solving the full linear system, and is also more susceptible to catastrophic cancellation.

Are there algorithms for determining $x_0$ alone whose expected computational complexity beats Gaussian elimination or LU factorization? Does the answer change if I am willing to accept an approximation for $x_0$, say from an iterative approach?

Edit:

I'll provide some additional context, which might help stimulate some ideas. In my application, I have a *sequence* of linear systems $A^{(n)} x^{(n)} = b^{(n)}$, with $n=1,2,\dots$ being the dimension of the system. Concretely,
$$
A^{(1)} x^{(1)} = b^{(1)} 
\to a_{00} x^{(1)}_0 = b_0 \\
A^{(2)} x^{(2)} = b^{(2)} 
\to \begin{bmatrix} 
a_{00} & a_{01} \\ a_{10} & a_{11} 
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x^{(2)}_0 \\ x^{(2)}_1
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
b_0 \\ b_1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and so on, with each linear system in the sequence simply appending another row and column to $A$ and appending an element to $b$, leaving the lower-order elements intact. As this sequence progresses, the value of $x_0^{(n)}$ should converge toward some limiting value $x^{(\infty)}_0$. So if it is possible to use the results of lower-order calculations $x^{(1)},\dots,x^{(n-1)}$ to compute $x_0^{(n)}$ in better than $O(n^3)$ time, that would be a useful answer as well.

Comment: I think if the matrix is sparse, there are some tricks that can be used to lower the computational cost, but not the complexity. But if it is dense, I don't know any methods which can achieve what you want.

Comment: There is an $O(n^3)$ implementation of Cramer's rule, although I don't know if it would work in your case:.    Ken Habgood; Itamar Arel (2012). "A condensation-based application of Cramerʼs rule for solving large-scale linear systems". Journal of Discrete Algorithms. 10: 98–109. doi:10.1016/j.jda.2011.06.007.

Comment: Apparently we need to find $x_0$ for many different cases. Is there anything in common for matrices A and vectors b for those cases? Or those are completely unrelated? I am wondering if it is possible to find $x_0$ for one given A,b and then to use that information for updated A and/or b.

Comment: Is $A$ special in any way? Symmetric, positive, non-negative, Hermitian, &c?

Comment: @MaximUmansky Very sharp observation. I've expanded the question to include more context about the problem which may help stimulate ideas along the lines of what you're thinking.

Comment: @Richard Unfortunately, $A$ does not have any special properties that I know of. It is real-valued and almost completely dense.

Comment: @Endulum, how about sequence extrapolation? Compute $x_0^{(n)}$ for some successive $n$ (by inverting some sufficiently large matrices), apply sequence extrapolation (e.g., Wynn's $\varepsilon$ method, Levin-type transformation, Richardson extrapolation, etc.). You need to try a lot of extrapolation methods or know the convergence behavior of $x_0^{(n)}$ to find a good one.

Comment: @cos_theta Yep, that's exactly what I plan to do with the sequence once I'm just looking for my options for optimally obtaining the first several entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, I think that the answer to your question about computing a single component is negative (unless you allow for Strassen-like methods, which *technically* are a positive answer since they have lower complexity than LU/Gaussian elimination).
The best way to compute determinants in practice is via Gaussian elimination, so that saves you nothing. (Also, note that the biggest issue with Cramer's rule is not cancellation but overflow/underflow).

However, your edit has a better answer than the original problem.

You can update most matrix factorizations in $O(n^2)$ after adding a column and/or a row to the matrix (or, in general, after a rank-1 update). In real life, this is usually done with QR and/or Cholesky rather than other factorizations, for stability reasons; look for `qrinsert` in your language of choice; e.g. [Python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr_insert.html) [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qrinsert.html).

So in your iteration when you enlarge the system at each step you can solve the full linear systems while paying $O(n^2)$ per step, by relying on factorization updates: at each step, you update the factorization by adding a row ($O(n^2)$), then adding a column ($O(n^2)$), then you use the factorization to solve the linear system ($O(n^2)$).

Comment: Lovely answer! QR insertion seems like exactly what I want. And after a cursory search, it seems like there are a handful of Fortran implementations as well.